# Problema al usar el AudioManager si se abren otras app

Tags: android, servicio, stream

Buenas a todos,

Tengo una aplicación que reproduce una radio en streaming a través de un servicio.
El servicio funciona perfectamente, puedo cerrar la aplicación y seguir escuchando la radio. Incluso si me llaman por teléfono la radio se para y cuando cuelga la llamada se vuelve a poner sola automáticamente. Hasta aquí todo perfecto.

El problema viene cuando se abre una aplicación que usa el sonido, como por ejemplo la de youtube. Cuando se empieza a reproducir el vídeo de youtube, la radio se para todo perfecto, pero cuando dejo de reproducir el vídeo, la radio no se reproduce hasta que no cierre la aplicación de youtube por completo. Tengo que ir a las tareas en segundo plano y cerrarla para que se vuelva a reproducir automáticamente.

Por otro lado que creo que tiene algo que ver con el mismo problema, es que reproduciendo la radio, yo abro un navegador web y si reproduzco algo desde el navegador, se escuchan la radio y la reproducción del navegador a la vez. Y me gustaría que pasara igual que con las llamadas.

El servicio es el siguiente:

```
public class RadioService extends Service implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

private final static String RADIO_STATION_URL = "http://URL";
private static RadioOnline radio;
private NotificationPanel nPanel;
private static boolean value = false;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    try {
        radio = new RadioOnline(RADIO_STATION_URL, this);
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        radio.initializeMediaPlayer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Creado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        if (radio.isNetworkConnected(this)){
            nPanel = new NotificationPanel(this, radio);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Iniciado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    nPanel.notificationCancel();
    try {
        if (radio.stopPlaying()){
            nPanel.notificationCancel();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }finally {
        nPanel.notificationCancel();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Detenido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange)
    {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:

            try {
                if (radio.isNetworkConnected(this)){

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            if(radio.getPlayer().isPlaying()) {
                try {
                    radio.stopPlaying();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, estoy aprendiendo mucho gracias a esta comunidad.

Comment: funcionan igual "youtube" y "teléfono", en ambos casos se cierra la aplicación (al finalizar la llamada se cierra la aplicación) y comienza el sonido.

Comment: prueba usando esto:     case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
    try {
        if (radio.isNetworkConnected(this)){
            nPanel = new NotificationPanel(this, radio);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Reiniciado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Muchas gracias, para solucionar el problema web me vino genial, pero aún sigo teniendo el problema de tener que cerrar por completo youtube. Aunque es un mal menor me gustaría solucionarlo.

Comment: Si es la solución que esperabas la agregare como respuesta, y espero que la marques como respuesta correcta. Esto ayudará a futuros desarrolladores

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes agregar esto:

```
case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN: 
    try {
       if (radio.isNetworkConnected(this)){
           nPanel = new NotificationPanel(this, radio); 
       }
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Reiniciado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```